# Trouble with generator object not casting to list being returned from map function

Tags: python, generator

I am having an issue to where I am attempting to yield a dictionary back to the caller and casting the returned generator to a list, however when i print `event_list`, it still states that it is a generator object.

My goal is to multi-process a function by a list of files that will create a local dictionary and return said dictionary to the caller so that I can make a single list containing the returned dictionaries from that method. Not entirely sure where I am going wrong.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import json

class Events(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._parse_events()

    def _parse_events(self):
        my_list = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
        event_results = list()

        with mp.Pool() as pool:
            results = list(pool.map(self._get_event, my_list))

        for result in results:
            event_results.append(result)

        print(event_results) # <------- this somehow returns a generator although I thought i casted the return to a list

        print(sum(event_results, [])) # <--------- this doesn't work now that im dealing with a generator rather than the original list


    def _get_event(self, filename):
        key_identifier = 'role'

        with open(filename, 'r') as data:
            for line in data:
                if key_identifier in line:
                    temp_dict = dict()
                    try:
                        contents = json.loads(line)
                        temp_dict['UTC'] = contents.get('utc', 'None')
                        temp_dict['ServiceID'] = contents[key_identifier].get('ServiceID', 'None')
                    except (KeyError, ValueError):
                        continue

                    if temp_dict: yield temp_dict
```

Comment: I don't see how `event_results` could be a generator. Regardless, `_get_event()` shouldn't return `event_list` (which is empty anyway) because it's a generator function — it should be allow to just end after the `with` finishes.

Comment: @martineau agree about your last statement, that return was left over from when I was appending to the list rather than yielding. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating a list of generators. It's not the top level object that's not of the right type, it's the inner values, and you're not casting those at all. It may be that you intended to, as you currently have a mostly pointless extra loop where you move the generator objects from `results` into `event_results` without doing anything else to them.

You could change that loop to put the inner values into the list:

```
for result in results:
    event_results.extend(result) # extend consumes an iterable
```

Or if you want a list of lists, rather than just one single flat list, you could do:

```
for result in results:
    event_results.append(list(result)) # convert each generator into a list
```